# Problems with list-group-custom from Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new at web programming (one night learning PHP and some little experience with css). My problem is at using the Custom Content List Group from Bootstrap, I get this result:
[image]

Using this code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bs-example" data-example-id="list-group-custom-content">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 id="list-group-item-heading" class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
        <a class="anchorjs-link" href="#list-group-item-heading">
         <span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 id="list-group-item-heading" class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#list-group-item-heading"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 id="list-group-item-heading" class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#list-group-item-heading"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

that I grabbed from Bootstrap official page (by pressing rigth click, Inspect element, and robbing the html code) 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group

[image: as you can see, is pretty different]

as you can see, is pretty different. How can I make my page be like the bootstrap sample? What changes should I need to do, to make it look similar?

I add the container to my 'Index.php' page by using this code.

```
<body>
        <?php include('templates/nav-bar.php') ?>
        <?php include(D_SITES.find_reference($dbc,$pageid))?>
        <?php include('templates/footer.php') ?>
</body>
```

The middle instruction searches for the reference to the php file in the database, and that file contains the code from above.
I add the bootstrap framework using CDN

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Mr Gus</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">I don't think we're alike at all, Mr. White. You're not a cautious man at all. Your partner was late. And he was high.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Mr Gus</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">I don't think we're alike at all, Mr. White. You're not a cautious man at all. Your partner was late. And he was high.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Mr Gus</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">I don't think we're alike at all, Mr. White. You're not a cautious man at all. Your partner was late. And he was high.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

See : https://jsfiddle.net/c396r41j/

Comment: It stills occuping all the space :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Mr Gus</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text">I don't think we're alike at all, Mr. White. You're not a cautious man at all. Your partner was late. And he was high.</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Mr Gus</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text">I don't think we're alike at all, Mr. White. You're not a cautious man at all. Your partner was late. And he was high.</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Mr Gus</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text">I don't think we're alike at all, Mr. White. You're not a cautious man at all. Your partner was late. And he was high.</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```